# No WiFi on HP Stream (Atom)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, broadcom, realtek

Months ago I bought a HP Stream (Atom) laptop for my son. It came originally with Windows 8 with a free upgrade to Windows 10. It has 20GB storage which was enough for Windows 8 but not enough for Windows 10 - today I just can't update Windows as there's no space - even with an extra 60GB SD card added to the system.

I decided to install Ubuntu on it, but trying first before actually doing it. Ubuntu 16 ran nicely from a USB thumb drive, but the original Wireless adapter, a Broadcomm BCM43142 wasn't recognized by Ubuntu. I then decided to buy another Wireless adapter (TP-LINK TL-WN725N) which is based on the Realtek TRL8188EU.

The TP-LINK adapter was promptly recognized when I tested in my Ubuntu 17 desktop, but not on my son's laptop, even after trying it from Ubuntu 17. 
I don't know why the wireless adapter is recognized and works from a desktop but not from my son's laptop, under the exact same version of the OS.

My son's laptop (HP Stream) is a very light, low end laptop: it doesn't have any network interfaces, aside the wireless one. Right now neither the original Broadcomm BCM43142 nor the additional Realtek TRL8188EU wireless adapters are recognized.

Both show when I run lsusb command but neither are recognized by Ubuntu. In WiFi Settings, I get only a "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" message.

I feel my son is locked in a slugish Windows laptop, and I don't see how I can install Ubuntu (or even Lubuntu) without having at least one of these wireless adapters working.

Suggestive fixes should consider the fact that, from the laptop, there's no network connection.

Note: Ubuntu 16 and 17 were tested in my son's laptop from a USB thumbdrive, without installing on the machine. Not sure if it makes any difference in regards recognizing the wireless adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Although neither the original Broadcom BCM43142 nor the additional  TP-LINK TL-WN725N (Realtek TRL8188EU) wireless adapters were not recognized by Ubuntu while running the OS from a thumb drive, both were recognized after Ubuntu was installed. I think the drivers were not available while running the OS from a thumb drive. After I took a leap of faith and installed Ubuntu on the laptop, the TP-LINK wireless adapter was recognized. With that done, I got connectivity to the Internet and could then install the drivers (proprietary) for the original Broadcom wireless adapter. Bottom line, both wireless adapters now work nicely.